# Using openxlsx startRow parameter to pick first row based on the contents of the file

Tags: r, openxlsx

I know that the `startRow` parameter in the `read.xlsx` function in `openxlsx` allows me to read a file starting at a designated row.  I have to load 300 xlsx files, unfortunately, the number of rows that I want to skip varies between the files.  I always want the first row to contain the word "CPT" in the second column.  Is there a way to set the `startRow` on a text matching parameter?  In the picture below, I would set the startRow to 6, but in other cases its 4 or 3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is good idea to read twice (1st: read a few rows of col1&2 and get `startRow`).
Note: I supposed the cells you want to skip is on col1 (at least).
And with `for`, `sapply` or  etc, you can do it with all files.

```
library(openxlsx)
tmp <- read.xlsx(file, colNames = FALSE, rows = 1:10, cols = 1:2, 
                 skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
st <- min(grep("CPT", tmp[[2]]))
d <- read.xlsx(file, startRow = st)
```